# Why drush is not maintained in drupal.org?

Tags: drush

[Drush project page](https://drupal.org/project/drush) says, "The Drush project has moved to Github."

I would like to know if there is any specific reason for moving to Github.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The motivation for moving to GitHub is discussed on our [wiki page](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/wiki/Migration-From-Drupal.org):

> Drupal.org is poor fit for Drush as we get features we don't want on our project page
>
> - Usage statistics (Drush isn't a module and thus can't report usage)
> - Release names must map to a single Drupal version
> - [The issue to fix this stuff](https://drupal.org/node/322626) is nearly five years old.